# How to use didSelectRowAtIndexPath uitableviewdelegate method

Tags: ios4

I am trying to create following functionality...

my tableview load names from sqlit3 db and with this name there are numbers associated with it and i want the value of this number in textfield when i select the name from my tableview.
 i tried it but not getting logic can any one please give me solution on this ...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    textfield.text = [yourarry ObjectAtIndex:inexPath.row];
}
```

Use this event to get the selected row value..